# REGEXP js dot not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use regex to validate a form in js, but I encountered a problem, which I could no google successfully.

When I create any RegExp in js, for example with the `/(.)*/` the test function returns false no matter on what I test it... In php and regex online editors it works fine.

I tried to google it, but without any success, it seems as everyone is using the:

`var regexp = /expression/`

My code:

```
var reg = new RegExp("/(.)+/", "g");
console.log("Regexp:" + reg.test("a"));
```

Also I have been told that the regex in php should be compatible with the regex in js...

Comment: What does your regex test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You either need to remove the quotes, or remove the slashes. [See the documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
var reg = new RegExp(/(.)+/, "g");
console.log("Regexp:" + reg.test("a"));
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but is there any big difference between these two solutions? removing the quotes or removing the slashes?

Comment: It's basically run-time vs evaluation time compilation.  Which becomes more apparent in a loop with a large number of iterations.

Answer (score 4):

When you're using the `RegExp` object you shouldn't add `/` signs in the definitions. Simply use `var reg = new RegExp("(.)+", "g");`

Comment: Ty, it works, but also http://stackoverflow.com/a/43944221/5070552 works, is there any big difference?

Comment: _Use literal notation when the regular expression will remain constant_ The [Description section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) gives a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between JS and PHP Regex is:
javascript : /[a-z]+/
php        : '/[a-z]+/'

Simply the single quotes on each end of the regex expression.